# Using data on dispatched event and trigger div

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a component that dispatches a browser event with an object

```
// Livewire Component Method

public function passToDashboard($dataId)
{
    $data = Model::find($dataId);
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('show-data', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

Now on my dashboard blade view i've got

```
<div class="some-classes" x-data="{dataDisplay:false}">
    <div x-show="dataDisplay">
        {{-- This is where i want to use the object --}}
        {{ $data->title }}
    </div>
</div>

<script>
   window.addEventListener('show-data', data => {
    console.log(data.detail.title); // outputs title just fine
   })
</script>
```

The question is, how to 'unhide' the dataDisplay and how to show it with the passed data? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for these events directly on the element using @event-name.window="dataDisplay = true"

To get the event data, you use the $event variable and it should be under $event.detail.data.title

Use x-text to get the text onto the element. See my full example below.

So in your case:

```js
<div class="some-classes" x-data="{dataDisplay:false, title: ''}" @event-data.window="dataDisplay = true; title = $event.detail.data.title">
  <div x-show="dataDisplay">
    <h3 x-text="title"></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

The documentation for this can be found here: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#browser

Do notice I changed the event name, because it does apparently not work if you start the event name with "show". When I changed to "event-data" or anything else it started working again.